# Foxpro FPD DBF Open Issues

Tags: foxpro, dbf

I am currently developing an integration in C# to talk with an old Foxpro system.

The purpose of this software in reporting & auditing.

I am have following issue when connecting with FPD using ODBC.

1. I am unable to open shared file (If file being opened any where else)
2. I am unable to see rows marked for deletion.

Comment: The commands [`SET EXCLUSIVE OFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/3t2wew80(v=vs.80).aspx) and [`SET DELETED OFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/87tc2sc3(v=vs.80).aspx) come to mind

Answer (score 1):

Using C#, I would skip ODBC, but instead use [VFP OleDB Provider download here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839)

Then, you can create a connection -- connect to the PATH where the table(s) are located, not a connection to the specific table.  Then, create OleDbCommand object and send your SQL-Select, Insert, Update, Delete.   DO PARAMETERIZED queries to prevent problems.

[I have offered many answers associated with VFP, OleDb, C# connection, query, updates, etc so you can easily find many other options from there.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:74195%5Bvfp%5D%5Boledb%5D)